# Настройка статического сайта на Nginx

Tags: nginx

Я пытаюсь настроить отдачу статического сайта (index.html + css-файлы) с помощью Nginx. Домен сайта кириллический. Что я сделал:
1. Создал по адресу /var/www/ новую папку blago и поместил в нее index.html 
2. Добавил в sites-available новый конфиг blago

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/blago
```

со следующим содержимым

```
server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;

       server_name  www.xn--80acjdwguci9fxb.xn--p1ai  xn--80acjdwguci9fxb.xn--p1ai;

       access_log    /var/log/nginx/shkolapobedy.access.log;
       error_log     /var/log/nginx/shkolapobedy.error.log;

       root /var/www/blago;
       index index.html;

       location / {
               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }
}
```

3. Cоздал ссылку на новый конфигурационный файл в Nginx в дирректории sites-enabled

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/blago /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

4. Проверил

```
sudo nginx -t
```

5. Рестартнул

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Так как я в этом совсем новичек, ничего не заработало. Подскажите чего не хватает?

Comment: Записи в DNS сервере для xn--80acjdwguci9fxb.xn--p1ai

Comment: Т.е. конфиг рабочий?

Comment: у домена айпи правильно прописан?

Comment: Уточню, я к домену доступа не имею

Comment: *Уточню, я к домену доступа не имею* — а что вы тогда хотите от нас, здесь присутствующих? чтоб мы взломали регистратора или выкупили доменное имя у владельца?

Comment: Не правильно поняли) я уточню у владельца домена сделал ли он запись А. Так как у меня нет возможности проверить это лично. А пока ответ на вопрос правильно ли сконфигурирован конфиг - былобы уже неплохо.

Comment: Добавили запись в DNS, заработало 'с без' www, на www отдает заглушку Nginx.